# Call function from another class - field - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm struggling with this and I'm not so clear about it.

Let's say I have a function in a class:

```
class my_class(osv.Model):
    _name = 'my_class'
    _description = 'my description'

    def func (self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
            res = dict((id, 0) for id in ids)
    sur_res_obj = self.pool.get('contratos.user_input')
    for id in ids:
        res[id] = sur_res_obj.search(cr, uid,  # SUPERUSER_ID,
            [('contratos_id', '=', id), ('state', '=', 'done')],
            context=context, count=True)
    return res
    columns = {
        'function': fields.function(_get_func,
        string="Number of completed Contratos", type="integer"),
my_class()
```

Now I want to call this very same function from another class-object:

```
class another_class(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'my_class'
    _name = 'my_class'

    columns = {
        'another_field' : fields.related('function', 'state', type='char', string = "Related field which calls a function from another object"), 
    }
```

But this isn't working, I'm very confused about this, how can I call a function from another object in Odoov8?

I've heard about `self.pool.get` but I'm not really sure on how to invoke it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using odoo8 you should use the new API. from the docs

> In the new API the notion of Environment is introduced. Its main
>   objective is to provide an encapsulation around cursor, user_id,
>   model, and context, Recordset and caches

```
def my_func(self):
    other_object = self.env['another_class']
    other_object.create(vals) # just using create as an example
```

That means you don't need to explicity pass `cr`, `uid`, `ids`, `vals` and `context` in your methods anymore and you don't use `self.pool.get()` even though it's still there for backward compatibility

`env` is dictionary-like object that is used to store instances of the Odoo models and other information so you can access other objects and their methods from any Odoo model.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I'm kind of stuck into OpenERP 7 api, I'm trying this, if I have more trouble I'll open another question, Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
def example(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    otherClass = self.pool.get('my_class')
    ...
    otherClass.func(cr, uid, otherClassIds, name, arg, context)
```

[More information.](http://abhishek-jaiswal.github.io/blog/odoov8/2014/11/15/odoo-v8-decorator.html)