# Calling method and field from other model in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

these are my 1st model, method, and fields

```
class overtime(models.Model):
   _name = 'overtime'

   def calc_overtime(self, start_date, end_date):
      #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
      f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
      d1 = datetime.strptime(start_date, f)
      d2 = datetime.strptime(end_date, f)
      timeDiff = d2-d1
      hours = float(timeDiff.total_seconds()/3600)
      return hours

   start_date = fields.Datetime('Start Date', required=True, default=lambda *a : time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"+" "+"%H:%M:%S")
             , readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})
   end_date = fields.Datetime('End Date', required=True, default=lambda *a : time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"+" "+"%H:%M%S")
             , readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})
```

and these are my 2nd model, method and field

```
class overtime_details(models.Model):
    _name='overtime_details'


    def function(self):
        "calling calc_overtime"

    ovrtm = fields.Float('Overtime Hour(s)')
```

how do i call the calc_overtime method, start_date and end_date as parameters, in the overtime details class by using "self.pool.get" 
or "self.env". and make the result as ovrtm field's value. Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to calculate the nb of hours in the first class, The function sould be in the second class, and add a One2many field.

class overtime(models.Model):
     _name = 'overtime'

```
 start_date = fields.Datetime('Start Date', required=True, default=lambda *a : time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"+" "+"%H:%M:%S")
           , readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})
 end_date = fields.Datetime('End Date', required=True, default=lambda *a : time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"+" "+"%H:%M%S")
           , readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})



class overtime_details(models.Model):
  _name='overtime_details'

 def compute_houres(self, start_date, end_date):
    d1 = self.overtime_id.end_date
    d2 = self.overtime_id.start_date
    f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    d1 = datetime.strptime(start_date, f)
    d2 = datetime.strptime(end_date, f)
    timeDiff = d2-d1
    hours = float(timeDiff.total_seconds()/3600)
    self.ovrtm = hours


  overtime_id = fields.Many2one('overtime', 'Réference', ondelete='cascade'),
  ovrtm = fields.Float(compute='compute_houres')
```

Comment: thanks, ur answer solves my prob. but would you give the solution if i still want to call the func from the 1st class ?

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242600/call-function-from-another-class-field-odoo-v8